# Autolayout interface usability issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

After i select a particular constraint from the constraint list for a view how do i go back to the constraint list again. I dont see any other option other than going back to the view which i need to edit and it is one among many views and again selecting the constraints tab in the inspector window.

I need to go back to this window so i can continue editing other constraints.

[image: I need to go back to this window after finishing what i need to do for a particular constraint.]

From this window.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's either these Back and Forward buttons, or Ctrl + Cmd + Left/Right

[image]